# How to configure Coldfusion web root location

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, coldfusion

I have CF9 on Windows Web Server 2008 R2 using IIS 7.

Initially it was installed to use IIS7, but then I amended the jrun.xml file to use the internal CF web server and restarted and was then able to serve cfm pages from cf_root/wwwroot using the built in server.

I'm now trying to switch back to use IIS, so I re-edited the jrun.xml, restarted CF and IIS for good measure, however when I access on `http://localhost` I am getting static html pages served from C:\inetpub\wwwroot (the correct default IIS root dir) but my cfm pages are coming from d:\coldfusion9\wwwroot (my cf installation root).

I've clearly got some config setting borked, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: Never mind it was solved with a hard server re-boot

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your setup 100%, but IIS will only serve files out of the Home Directory as defined in the properties for the website in IIS. You need to have your ColdFusion files in the IIS webroot in order for them to run.

If you copy your files from your d drive to the proper wwwroot directory in IIS, and they still don't run, then you'll need to make sure you run the wsconfig utility to hook up IIS to the ColdFusion runtimes.

HTH,

Dan